# How to trigger a dojoEvent with VBA

Tags: vba, dom, dojo

I have loaded a Webpage into an Internetexplorer Object in Excel and would like to trigger a dojoEvent with VBA.

```
<a href="#" wairole="button" dojoattachpoint="focusNode" 
ojoattachevent="onclick:_onClick" class="foo" id="lp-btn" widgetid="lp-btn">
<span dojoattachpoint="containerNode" class="btn-cnt">Login</span></a>
```

In fact I want to click the Login button with VBA. So far I tried:
1)

```
Dim evt As Object
Set evt = IEdoc.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
evt.initEvent "click", True, False
IEdoc.getElementById("lp-btn").dispatchEvent evt
```

2)

```
IEdoc.getElementById("lp-btn").click
```

Both variants do not work. I am using IE9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as:

```
Dim IEdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
set IEdoc = IEapp.Document
IEdoc.getElementById("lp-btn").Click
```